# Query ListSubscribers DataView for EmailAddress, CreatedDate

Tags: marketing-cloud

It's my understanding that _ListSubscribers "CreatedDate" refers to the date the Subscriber was added to a particular list (not the original ingestion into the All Subscribers master list). I've got a DataExtension ready with "EmailAddress" and "CreatedDate" (type: Date) fields but when I run the following query, only the Email Addresses are populated.

```
SELECT EmailAddress, CreatedDate
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = i
-- AND CreatedDate = GETDATE()
```

I've tried setting the Data Type to text for the CreatedDate field with the same result. I'd ultimately like to take this one step further to include the commented line and only retrieve records added on the date the query is run, but after initial testing I've realized the inclusion of CreateDate was failing altogether, so I'm starting smaller.

Comment: its unclear what your exact question is. can you be more specific please on what you are after ?

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna - I am attempting to populate a DataExtension from a Query Activity using the [ListSubscribers DataView](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/) in Exacttarget but so far I am only able to populate the EmailAddress field. The CreatedDate remains empty for all records.

Comment: CreatedDate is "The date the subscriber was added to the list".  Your query looks correct and I just ran it without any issues in my own account for testing.  It pulled back a date similar to 8/30/2013 4:09 PM.  CreatedDate must be a "date" data type.  I would re-run it and place it in a program to make sure it runs successfully as I don't see any issues with SELECT EmailAddress, CreatedDate
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE ListID = 12345

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that I was not missing something @Jeremy! I decided to start with a new DataExtension, adjusted my Query to target it, re-ran the Program and returned CreatedDate(s) across the board. Maybe I just needed a pep-talk and a clean slate. QQ: you mention putting the query in a program - this is the only way I know to execute them but if there's another way that I'm missing please share!

Comment: Glad to hear that did the trick.  You can run them manually by checking the box and hitting start but this will not notify you once complete or errorred.  Always best to place in a program in my opinion.  Thanks!